# Django Aggregation - Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field

Tags: django, aggregate-functions, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm trying to achive an Aggregation Query and that's my code:

```
TicketGroup.objects.filter(event=event).aggregate(
                           total_group=Sum(F('total_sold')*F('final_price')))
```

I have 'total_sold' and 'final_price' in TicketGroup object and all what I want to do is sum and multiply values to get the total sold of all TicketGroups together.

All I get is this error:

> Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field

What I am doing wrong, since I'm calling 'total_group' as my output field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

By `output_field` Django means to provide field type for the result of the `Sum`.

```
from django.db.models import FloatField, F
total_group=Sum(F('total_sold')*F('final_price'), output_field=FloatField())
```

should do the trick.

Comment: use output_field=DecimalField() for currency calculations

Answer (score 54):

I had to use something different in order to make my query work. Just output_field wont solve it. I needed a simple division between two aliases. These are output of two annotations.

```
from django.db.models import FloatField, ExpressionWrapper, F

distinct_people_with_more_than_zero_bill = Task.objects.filter(
    billable_efforts__gt=0).values('report__title').annotate(
    Count('assignee', distinct=True)).annotate(
    Sum('billable_efforts'))

annotate(yy=ExpressionWrapper(F('billable_efforts__sum') / F('assignee__count'), output_field=FloatField()))
```

The key here is **ExpressionWrapper**.
Without this, you will get an error: **received non-expression(s)**

The hint came for Django documentation itself, which says:

> If the fields that you’re combining are of different types you’ll need
>   to tell Django what kind of field will be returned. Since F() does not
>   directly support output_field you will need to wrap the expression
>   with ExpressionWrapper

Link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/

Comment: If you need this annotate in a Subquery, you probably only need the output_field set on the Subquery and an ExpressionWrapper is not necesssary.