# Sum Product using Django ORM

Tags: python, django-models, django-queryset

I need to calculate the sumproduct of two fields from Django queryset.

I have checked the answer in 
[Django Aggregation: Summation of Multiplication of two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165636/django-aggregation-summation-of-multiplication-of-two-fields)
but it doesnt work.
They suggest the following code for django < 1.8:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
MyModel.objects.filter(<filters>).aggregate(Sum('field1', field="field1*field2"))
```

which returns the sum of the 'field1' not the defined field="field1*field2"

and for django >= 1.8

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F
MyModel.objects.filter(<filters>).aggregate(Sum(F('field1')*F('field2')))
```

which returns TypeError: Complex aggregates require an alias

Comment: What is your Django version ?

Comment: @MohammadUmair My Django version is 2.1.2 and I checked the second code in the link which was suggested to use for django >= 1.8 but it did not work as well

Comment: from django.db.models import Sum, F
MyModel.objects.filter(<filters>).aggregate(Sum(F('field1')*F('field2')))

Comment: I get the error "Complex aggregates require an alias" on this one

Comment: You're not specifying where to store that sum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F
MyModel.objects.filter(<filters>).aggregate(sum=Sum(F('field1')*F('field2')))["sum"]
```

Comment: Tried it right now. I get the FieldError: Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I searched this error and resolved it through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546108/django-aggregation-expression-contains-mixed-types-you-must-set-output-field